# configuring ssl for WCF

Tags: wcf

Can anybody tell me what is the difference between httpcfg.exe and netsh.exe which is used to set up ssl. Currently i am using netsh but i've seen in some videos they don't use netsh but instead use httpcfg. Can somebody throw some light upon it as to when to use httpcfg ?

Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in version of Windows hosting the service. Netsh is used in newer versions (7, 2008), httpcfg is used in Windows 2003.